# How do I pass data to a global partial in Symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I want to create a partial for a navigation bar which requires data from my DB. I've created a `_top_nav.php` partial at the global level of my frontend app. I'm then including the partial in my main layout and passing the data to the view in the normal way. However, it seems you can't pass data to a partial via the layout.

What's the best way to do this in Symfony 1.4 - should I be using a slot or a component instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use a component instead, as described in the "Gentle Introduction' Symfony 1.4 documentation (Section on Components)